# Displaying distinct values in a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview, ado.net

I want to return the unique `Customer_ID` and `Customer_Name` from a set of purchases made in a MSSQL db table.  The table contains other columns.  I created a SQL scalar query inside of the table adapter wizard for the respective table.

I created a Scalar query using the following sql code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Cust_ID, Cust_Name
FROM tblAllOrders
Where Date = cast (GETDATE() as DATE)
```

When I previewed the query results it is exactly what I wanted.

I tried to assign the query results to the datagridview like this:

```
datagridview.DataSource = tblAllOrdersTableAdapter.ScalarQuery();
```

but this is not working the `datagridview` remains empty.

Any suggestions?  I would rather not use `SQLCommand`.  The research I did said to use a Scalar Query but as I am receiving multiple rows, I am not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: A scalar query can only return one column.  You may be getting an exception that you are not seeing, try to put some breakpoints in your code and see if `tblAllOrdersTableAdapter.ScalarQuery()` is returning any results.

Comment: do you know what `Execute Scalar` means / returns.. it will only return the first row found where that condition is met.. and I am quite sure you do not want just 1 `Cust_Id`  returned. [Sql Basics Tutorial](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm) I would google what `DataAdapter.DefaultView` does and I would bind my datasource using that method.. however there are several different approaches you can take to bind data to a DataGridView for example `DataTable, List<T>, DataSet..`

Comment: nevermind I created a workaround

Comment: There's no need for a workaround.  Just do it properly in the first place, i.e. don't create a scalar query.  Create a table-valued query or whatever it's called, i.e. return a tabular result set instead of just a single value.